# Dependency property not working in Windows Phone 8.1 App

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I new to windows phone development so may be this question may look odd to you all expert. I have one datatemplate dependency property which is working fine in windowsphone 8.0 silverlight project bu t when I try to use same property in Windowsphone 8.1 App it is not working. Please note that I have made all namespace changes which are required to work in windowsphone 8.1 application. Please check the code below for more details.
XAML code

```
            <lazy:NewListBox x:Name="MainListBox" Margin="0,0,-12,0" Opacity="0.3" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" >
            <lazy:NewListBox.LoadedItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Height="100">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=StoreImage}" Grid.Column="0" Stretch="Uniform" 
                               Width="100" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="12,0"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="largeText" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=StoreName}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </lazy:NewListBox.LoadedItemTemplate>
    </lazy:NewListBox>
```

C# code

```
  public class NewListBox : ListBox
{
    #region LoadedItemTemplate property

    /// <summary>
    /// The "full" template to use when an item is fully loaded and visible in the list
    /// </summary>
    public DataTemplate LoadedItemTemplate
    {
        get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(LoadedItemTemplateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LoadedItemTemplateProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// DependencyProperty that backs the <see cref="LoadedItemTemplate"/> property
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LoadedItemTemplateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "LoadedItemTemplate",
      typeof(DataTemplate),
      typeof(NewListBox),
      null);
}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong Any help is appreciated 
Thanks.
Mayank Rajpura.

Comment: Do you get any error message? 
What exactly is the Problem?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I do not get any error message. The list box show only class name not a template.

Comment: Please check following example  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ptorr/2010/10/12/procrastination-ftw-lazylistbox-should-improve-your-scrolling-performance-and-responsiveness/  This example is working fine as Windowsphone 8.0 silverlight but when I tried to migrate it to WindowsPhone 8.1 Runtime App the LoadedItemTemplate dependency property is not working. I don't know why? this is simple dependency property.

Comment: The code you show seems to be alright... What class name does it show? And are you sure the problem lies within this LoadedItemTemplate dependency?

Comment: The class name as code in screen is NewListBox but if you download the sample from mdsn link which i provided in previous comment than there is class called LazyListBox. from that sample I have just taken only dependency property and created new class named NewListBox but it wan't work.